# PHP: select form menu list error

Tags: php, mysql, sql, forms, select

Hi my select menu list is not working.

```
<?php
    <tr>
        <select name="package">
        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
        if(isset($_POST['package'])) echo "<option>" . $_POST['package'] . "</option>"; 
        </tr>

?>
```

Help, would be appreciated.
Many thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: Why would html work inside php? You have to either `echo '<select....'` or get your html out of `<?php ?>`

Comment: Are you trying to select the default option to be displayed? i.e show  to the user the option they previously selected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have mixed php with html and also you didnt close SELECT tag.

try that:

```
    <tr>
    <select name="package">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['package'])){ echo "<option value='".$_POST['package'] ."'>" . $_POST['package'] . "</option>"}; 
    ?>
    </select> <-----you missed this
    </tr>
```

when using php and html you need either :

```
 <?php  echo "<select name='package'>
              <option value='volvo'>Volvo</option>
              ....................................";
 ?>
```

or the code i provided above without  before and after html code.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use html inside php directory. If you want to use html mixed with php either do it using echo or outside `<?php //inside ?> //outside`. Here try this.

```
<tr>
    <select name="package">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['package']))
        echo "<option>" . $_POST['package'] . "</option>"; 
    ?>
</tr>
```